# Best software (open-source if possible) for modelling free boundary problems and general constitutive relations in Computational Mechanics.

Tags: computational-mathematics, math-software

I am in search of a good software package (open-source if possible) with capabilities of modelling free boundaries, polymeric behavior (i.e. stress is defined by a evolutionary PDE) and multi-physics problems (thermomechanical behavior, photochemical reactions, etc.)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Computational Science Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) is probably the (way) better place for this, you might want to consider moving the question there.

Comment: @DanDoe Thank you for your suggestion!